# ffmpeg - How to (programmatically) copy a stream's side data?

Tags: ffmpeg

My app is a tag editor (eg ID3) written in Swift for macOS. I'm using ffmpeg as my library to perform the tag editing. When the user is done editing, the app should save the changes to (essentially) a modified copy of the original file. **I'm able to copy everything I need (from input -> output file) EXCEPT "side data".**

In other words, I'm doing the programmatic equivalent of:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -metadata key1=value1 -metadata key2=value2 -codec copy output.mp3
```

So, **output.mp3 must be identical to input.mp3, except for the few metadata changes made by the user**.

**What I have working so far**

I'm able to copy the audio stream and all associated metadata (tags), as is, from input.mp3 to output.mp3.

**The problem**

My input.mp3 happens to have some ***side data*** (see below), which does ***not*** get copied over to output.mp3. How to copy side data ? To be honest, I don't even know what side data is, and the documentation is not very helpful.

ffprobe gives the following output (snippet) for the input.mp3's side data that looks like:

```
Side data:
      replaygain: track gain - -9.200000, track peak - unknown, album gain - unknown, album peak - unknown,
```

I want THIS  ^ to get copied over to output.mp3, but it does not :(

**Relevant code snippet** (format context initialization code omitted for conciseness)

```
let inAudioStream = inFormatContext!.pointee.streams.advanced(by: Int(audio_stream_index)).pointee!.pointee
var outAudioStream = outFormatContext!.pointee.streams.advanced(by: Int(audio_stream_index)).pointee!.pointee
            
/* Free existing side data*/
            
for i in 0..<Int(outAudioStream.nb_side_data) {
    av_free(outAudioStream.side_data[i].data)
}
            
av_freep(&(outAudioStream.side_data))
outAudioStream.nb_side_data = 0
            
/* Copy side data if present */
            
if let srcSideData = inAudioStream.side_data {
                
    let rawPtr: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = av_mallocz_array(Int(inAudioStream.nb_side_data),
                                                            MemoryLayout<AVPacketSideData>.size)
                
    outAudioStream.side_data = UnsafeMutablePointer<AVPacketSideData>(OpaquePointer(rawPtr))
    outAudioStream.nb_side_data = inAudioStream.nb_side_data
                
    for i in 0..<Int(inAudioStream.nb_side_data) {
                    
        let srcSideDataForI: AVPacketSideData = srcSideData[i]
                    
        let data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = av_memdup(srcSideDataForI.data, Int(srcSideDataForI.size))
        outAudioStream.side_data[i].type = srcSideDataForI.type
        outAudioStream.side_data[i].size = srcSideDataForI.size
        outAudioStream.side_data[i].data = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(OpaquePointer(data))
    }
}
            
status = avformat_write_header(outFormatContext, nil)
```

I got this logic from [this page](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/FFmpeg.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api/libavformat_2utils_8c_source.html). Is this ^ the right way to copy a stream's side data to the corresponding stream in the output file ? If not, how to do it ?

I have also tried the following functions with no luck:

```
av_stream_new_side_data(...)
av_stream_add_side_data(...)
```

Please ask for details if required, and I will provide them. Thanks very much !